# SharePoint 2010 workflow failed to run after a pause on SharePoint online list

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2010, custom-list, sharepoint-designer-workflow

There is a problem with SharePoint 2010 workflows, these workflows are there on SharePoint online list. And these sharepoint designer 2010 workflows are giving message as "Workflow failed to run" after a pause. I saw some solutions but those are for SharePoint onpremise environments. Any solution for SharePoint online, what do we need to do in this case. What is the cause of this error in SharePoint online environment. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: "Workflow Name" failed to run. It happens after a pause in workflow. This message it shows in Workflow History" list.